# Gokigen Naname - 1 and 2

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

> Here is a regular **Gokigen Naname** a.k.a **Slalom** a.k.a **Slant** puzzle.
> An online (mobile-friendly) version is available [here](https://puzz.link/p?gokigen/10/10/h66bb666b1617c2c7cgbb6172612bc76b726bg6bcbibh7b66bh16661c).

[image]

> **Rules**:
>
> - Put a slash (diagonal line) on each cell.
> - Each number in a circle denotes the number of slashes touching it.
> - The slashes should not form a loop.

Comment: This is a fun puzzle type, I love this! To clarify because I've never solved this type before: When you say the slashes should not form a loop, do you mean that the slashes shouldn't connect in a way that they form an enclosed loop anywhere in the puzzle?

Comment: Wow - I saw this and thought "Hashi!" which I love, but this is an awesome puzzle type of its own... Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Sciborg yep, that's correct :)

Comment: @athin Awesome! Great puzzle :)

Comment: If a corner does NOT have a number on it, does that mean that no lines are touching it?

Comment: @Vilx- A point without a number may touch to any number of lines

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get this far with relatively simple arguments based on a single clue at a time:

> [image]

Then, there's a useful pattern to notice:

> If two 1s in the middle of the grid are diagonally adjacent, they *cannot* be directly connected. That would create a loop around both of them.
>
>  This gives us a bit more:
>  [image]

That deduction can actually be extended:

> You can't have any "1-2-2-2-2-2-2-1" chains that don't touch the edge, with any number of 2s in the middle, because then you would draw a loop around all of them!
>
>  This lets you draw a slash on any 2 that has three 1s diagonally adjacent to it: the fourth edge must be used, because if it wasn't, you'd have a 1-2-1 chain and a loop.
>
>  [image]

And now it's time for a big deduction:

> [image]
>  The lines marked in red must connect to the edge of the grid *somehow*, because they cannot form a loop.
>
>  The yellow-highlighted 1 clues block them off -- they cannot traverse those clues on their path to the edge of the grid. This determines their escape routes:
>  [image]

And now we can finish off the puzzle, with just single-vertex deductions. The solution is below:

> [image]

Comment: At least one of your deductions is not based on rules given by OP. It is said nowhere that lines have to end at the edge. I searched for the rules and for this puzzle it is absolutely ok for a line just to stop anywhere in the grid. So I think your solution -though obeying all given rules- used wrong additional rules to be created... don't know if it matters though

Comment: Very nicely done! :)

Comment: @TorstenLink Apparently Deusovi noted above "The lines marked in red must connect to the edge of the grid somehow, because they cannot form a loop." This is actually not an added rule: lines have to end at the edge can be deducted by not forming a loop. Some sources "added" that rule just to help solver skip that deduction I think.

Comment: @TorstenLink If a line doesn't connect to the edge, the lines immediately around it form a loop. This works just like the 'chains' mentioned earlier, but on a bigger scale.

Comment: Love the solve.. I got stopped staring at exactly your screen 4 and 5 for ages!